# Images in ListControl are not Clear in MFC SDI application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I am working on one `MFC/SDI` project Where I am using `CListView` as a default View.

But the thing is, I have applied `ImageList` to the `CListCtrl` 
but these Images are not clearly displayed.
As shown in the picture below.

[image: This is snap of my output]

Below is the code for creating new image List.

Creating `ImageList` where `m_ImgList` is a member of `CImageList`.

```
if(m_ImgList->m_hImageList == NULL || m_ImgList->DeleteImageList() == TRUE)
{
    m_ImgList->Create(16,16, ILC_COLOR,0, 1);
}
```

Then I am  creating images by using BLOB data from database. 
Here, `pByte` is `BYTE*` to hold `BLOB` Data.

```
HGLOBAL hGlobal = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, nbytes+5);
LPVOID pV = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
memcpy(pV, pByte, nbytes);
GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
LPSTREAM pstm = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, &pstm);
CImage image;
image.Load(pstm);

if (image == NULL)
{
   image.Load(NILIMAGE);                    
}

CPaintDC dc(this);
CDC pMDC;

pMDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
CBitmap pb;
pb.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, iNewWidth, iNewHeight);
CBitmap *pob = (CBitmap*)pMDC.SelectObject(&pb);
image.StretchBlt(pMDC.m_hDC,0, 0, iNewWidth, iNewHeight,
                     0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
pMDC.SelectObject(pob);

Adding images to the image list

if((m_ImgList->Add(&pb, RGB(0,0,0)))== -1)
{
    _T("undone");
}
if(hGlobal != NULL)
  ::GlobalFree(hGlobal);
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?
Thank you in Advance.
and Sorry for bad English.

Comment: put your code where u create imagelist

Comment: I have added code please go through it.

Comment: What do if u type RGB(255,255,255)

Comment: Same Image Quality is showing on List control

Comment: `if(m_ImgList->m_hImageList == NULL || m_ImgList->DeleteImageList() == TRUE){ m_ImgList->Create(16,16, ILC_COLOR16,0, 256); }` try this create.

Comment: It is not working. it damage the displayed image.

Comment: I'm sure u must use `ILC_COLOR16` or `ILC_COLOR32` (this is number of colors)Try this  `(16,16,ILC_COLOR16,4,1)` or `ILC_COLOR16` change with `ILC_MASK`

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not working. With all options you have given.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the size of the original images-perhaps they lose quality because they are scaled down. If that is the case-your images are bigger than 16x16 then try to resize them to that size, and try to preserve their quality as best as you can. Hopefully this will help. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff can you give me some guidance about how I can resize image at runtime?

Comment: @AnkitB: Unfortunately no I can not, I had that same problem too, but couldn't find the solution that rescales bitmaps **without losing quality**. If your images are `bitmap`'s you will always lose quality. Your only chance in my opinion is to create new images from the existing ones, but to make them 16x16 in size and to sharpen them as much as you can. You could ask a question about this on `StackExchange-Graphic Design`. [Here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) is the link-hopefully they can help you out with the creation of new images.

Comment: @AnkitB: You could also try setting the stretch mode to `COLORONCOLOR` by using `SetStretchBltMode`-[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the documentation. Just a thought. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff  Sorry not working. But thanks for your support.

Comment: @AnkitB:It leaves only the scaling of images, as the source of the problem. I have an idea how we can determine if that is a problem: Find or create 16x16 image that has high quality you seek ( it is sharp enough, and so on ) and try to put it in the image list. If it is displayed properly-if you are satisfied with the result-then you just have to create new images from existing ones, and `StackExchange-Graphic Design` might be the place that can actually help you. Best regards and good luck.